# TS how use generic condition in class constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

why TS wont allow me do this?
From my test everything seem work ! no ?

```
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T) {
        // if KEYS.buffer ? is ValurBuffer or Valur ! why this no pass ?
        if (vtype === KEYS.buffer) {
            this.valur = new ValurBuffer(vtype);
        } else {
            this.valur = new Valur(vtype);
        }
    }
```

`Type 'Valur<T>' is not assignable to type 'T extends VKEY.buffer ? ValurBuffer<T> : Valur<T>'.ts(2322)`

here a context code.

```
const enum KEYS {
    string = 'string',
    number = 'number',
    boolean = 'boolean',
    array = 'array',
    buffer = 'buffer',
}

type VALUES = {
    readonly [KEYS.string]: string;
    readonly [KEYS.number]: number;
    readonly [KEYS.boolean]: boolean;
    readonly [KEYS.array]: Array<string | number | boolean>;
    readonly [KEYS.buffer]: ReadonlyArray<Token<any>>;
}


export class Token<T extends KEYS> {
    readonly valur: T extends KEYS.buffer ? ValurBuffer<T> : Valur<T>;
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T) {
        // if KEYS.buffer ? is ValurBuffer or Valur ! why this no pass ?
        if (vtype === KEYS.buffer) {
            this.valur = new ValurBuffer(vtype);
        } else {
            this.valur = new Valur(vtype);
        }
    }
}


class Valur<T extends KEYS> {
    readonly Token: Token<T>;
    protected _value: VALUES[T];
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T, shemas?: {}) {}
}
class ValurBuffer<T extends KEYS.buffer> {
    readonly Token: Token<T>;
    protected readonly _value: VALUES[T];
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    add(v:VALUES[T]){}
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T, shemas?: {}) {}
}


const test1 = new Token(KEYS.array)
test1.valur.value;
test1.valur.value = [5];
const test2 = new Token(KEYS.buffer);
test2.valur.value
test2.valur.value=[];
test2.valur.add([new Token(KEYS.boolean)])
```

[TSPLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=28&ssc=6&pln=21&pc=1#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgKZQK4FsEGkCiBNAZQQG9QFyF4AnASygHMEBeBAcmrvtYBoyK10AIyRVmbAcKo8%205QRAgAbJAEMoY1nMUqo0kBQTKqVZQE91h4yd37BqAGZ2R62w5G6AvqFBwTAByQIAGoAggAyAKo4RCykehRUKgAm0ApmANq4hAB0HAwAugBclHC0DADcMggJyslQqQgZ%20ARZEiKFCK1UFXHk1bX1jdmaSqrtw9rd%20n0p6ZnNFqbtwUamADy5jAA%20HRiSCNvjqgB8k-FJMw1zWS6OVO0ASud1JsuWqwAqEADWKKuqJkcTqBPCAvCAkAAPXwQKiIMAKZQwGAIT4-KAfZAQuAoRLIuZHEiVabPBAAN2UClQVCK70x2KguOwTWu9luCAA-EEKVSAEKskQfAlFQLcqiC07kSCwEqoMBwGEACl8qEEChoYCqT3qpJ8-hpAEpCT19AgAPSmhA0OxMob80ScmjIkWUqh81yiGFcl0IACECAA7gALMxwQOOjoQBC%20RHI9mVfRWhAKnV%20AJMdM25o3ESG2Im-MIUOOrLk70sKBIf1e3l25O6pD6iUm9zIBQwAJ5gv6IswEuisQVqvOql11ON%20MUEH6EEgsHwmPVsW0yH0xn4o1TLVmVEoGnfX7vIHG3xUCDYuVIRIIAD6pdQSGFYUiBDS7zyTfoSEQd6QCtzE96L8qTUHsslvbkkCbKcKHbb8IOTCD-2Nbsw17cDKTTMkIKgyopWoWV5SoJUVTVDViW1esaW4ShAyQdBEXZIpiHcXMZ1AeckUXN1bgxFccTxZlsyoAlO0AmoLh3KA9zRcVKhPM8kAvK9yLMdD70fCIolfd9Kk-OCML-DcCwSOBgMLVCwJ-HDjRqRJkwKEJNJfN99WY3DoHwuVFWVVV1U1cSSRTPUUWomBaPomBGJIFjouBMF2I8xBsXgABGAdKxRfcoAVK4FhMfVvCQVK%20xdEr726ZK4BSsqqDKzC0gAVh08BEsLIq4AAJnSqtJJywS7XHEBKo6mq6sK%20ARrvWqfyYNJmuG0bbIVNJB0ytE%20qGeQRigfU8n1IA)

Answer (score 2):

Because `valur` property is a black box. It is not evaluated yet in `Token` class declaration. It is still represents conditional type  `T extends KEYS.buffer ? ValurBuffer<T> : Valur<T>` instead of `ValurBuffer<T> | Valur<T>`

It is better to create `static init` method and overload it:

```js
const enum KEYS {
    string = 'string',
    number = 'number',
    boolean = 'boolean',
    array = 'array',
    buffer = 'buffer',
}

type VALUES = {
    readonly [KEYS.string]: string;
    readonly [KEYS.number]: number;
    readonly [KEYS.boolean]: boolean;
    readonly [KEYS.array]: Array<string | number | boolean>;
    readonly [KEYS.buffer]: ReadonlyArray<Token>;
}



export class Token{
    static init<T extends KEYS.buffer>(vtype: T): ValurBuffer<T>
    static init<T extends Exclude<KEYS, KEYS.buffer>>(vtype: T): Valur<T>
    static init<T extends KEYS.buffer>(vtype: T) {
        if (vtype === KEYS.buffer) {
            return new ValurBuffer(vtype);
        } else {
            return new Valur(vtype);
        }
    }
}


class Valur<T extends KEYS> {
    readonly Token: Token;
    protected _value: VALUES[T];
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T, shemas?: {}) { }
}
class ValurBuffer<T extends KEYS.buffer> {
    readonly Token: Token;
    protected readonly _value: VALUES[T];
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    add(v: VALUES[T]) { }
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T, shemas?: {}) { }
}


// Valur<KEYS.string | KEYS.number | KEYS.boolean | KEYS.array>
const test1 = Token.init(KEYS.array)
//  ValurBuffer<KEYS.buffer>
const test2 = Token.init(KEYS.buffer)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgKZQK4FsEGkCiBNAZQQG9QFyF4AnASygHMEBeBAcmrvtYBoyK10AIyRVmbAcKo8%205QRAgAbJAEMoY1nMUqo0kBQTKqVZQE91h4yd37BqAGZ2R62w5G6AvqFBwTAByQIAGoAggAyAKo4RCykehRUKgAm0ApmANq4hAB0HAwAugBclHC0DADcMggJyslQqQgZ%20ARZEiKFCK1UFXHk1bX1jdmaSqrtw9rd%20n0p6ZnNFqbtwUamADy5jAA%20HRiSCNvjqgB8k-FJMw1zWS6OVO0ASud1JsuWqwAqEADWKCegniAvICQEgAB6%20CBURBgBTKGAwBCfH5QWL6eDKOA0MAIOg0OAfZCguAoRIIq43ERHAAUADcfP4iu8AJRFQLKBSoKgAIXst1W5N5lMq6Mx2Nx%20PehOJUFJCBwoJhqESSH5TW42Ca10FVCO1LpfiQjJZQXZnNW8sVytVhHVAtcOqOwrgGKxOKgeIJYOlsrttz19MNiKZJEq%20hodgQtIDzCYLF9ImDqP0yd6SDgnLUUCQAHcTRzudqowamacU%205kAoYAEkympmmMx0c3nOUX-CXQxQAfoAQCgTC4Qi2fnPUSSWSmkcQz0qk96kiUIzvihSwhfFQIMSwMTEggAPo002BkIRKJpd55Ff0NMIA8cpBUxMd1PpqhqOAACxoMCy%208PK67FBVogt6oPeIFII%20076B%20X4-uBYjgf%20lSQLAJSoFukJUr4qCCAorrTM8N4Boy6owO%20SDoHCAD8RTEO4iYID2oD9vCzYFvaI7euOQzapONYzjUFzzlAi7Iiua4bkgW5IDuBH1L%20d6smEkQEGeF6VFewGHg%20U61jOL5vp%2034KaBSHTjUiS0kpJ6qeeDEAeQKHUOhcCYdhuH4bOZj6gyiKkeRlEwDRJD0SQjH-ECoAAPRRWx1rNBs%20watknRJeS8gjGo2xXAsJiOuA0DwAgxLwAAjGIwlZOKVI5SsJhMtFsVsTyHHxjqzGFYgJVwAATBVS5QFV7pwDVmoUlQDUgEAA)

If you want to stick with current `Token` implementation, try this:

```js
export class Token<T extends KEYS> {
    readonly valur: ValurBuffer<KEYS.buffer> | Valur<T>;
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T) {
        if (vtype === KEYS.buffer) {
            this.valur = new ValurBuffer(vtype);
        } else {
            this.valur = new Valur(vtype);
        }
    }
}
```

The whole code with second approach:

```js
const enum KEYS {
    string = 'string',
    number = 'number',
    boolean = 'boolean',
    array = 'array',
    buffer = 'buffer',
}

type VALUES = {
    readonly [KEYS.string]: string;
    readonly [KEYS.number]: number;
    readonly [KEYS.boolean]: boolean;
    readonly [KEYS.array]: Array<string | number | boolean>;
    readonly [KEYS.buffer]: ReadonlyArray<Token<any>>;
}


export class Token<T extends KEYS> {
    readonly valur: ValurBuffer<KEYS.buffer> | Valur<T>;
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T) {
        if (vtype === KEYS.buffer) {
            this.valur = new ValurBuffer(vtype);
        } else {
            this.valur = new Valur(vtype);
        }
    }
}


class Valur<T extends KEYS> {
    readonly Token: Token<T>;
    protected _value: VALUES[T];
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T, shemas?: {}) { }
}

class ValurBuffer<T extends KEYS.buffer> {
    readonly Token: Token<T>;
    protected readonly _value: VALUES[T];
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    add(v: VALUES[T]) { }
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T, shemas?: {}) { }
}


const test1 = new Token(KEYS.array)
test1.valur.value;
test1.valur.value = [5];
const test2 = new Token(KEYS.buffer);
test2.valur.value
test2.valur.value = [];
test2.valur.add([new Token(KEYS.boolean)])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgKZQK4FsEGkCiBNAZQQG9QFyF4AnASygHMEBeBAcmrvtYBoyK10AIyRVmbAcKo8%205QRAgAbJAEMoY1nMUqo0kBQTKqVZQE91h4yd37BqAGZ2R62w5G6AvqFBwTAByQIAGoAggAyAKo4RCykehRUKgAm0ApmANq4hAB0HAwAugBclHC0DADcMggJyslQqQgZ%20ARZEiKFCK1UFXHk1bX1jdmaSqrtw9rd%20n0p6ZnNFqbtwUamADy5jAA%20HRiSCNvjqgB8k-FJMw1zWS6OVO0ASud1JsuWqwAqEADWKKuqJkcTqBPCAvCAkAAPXwQKiIMAKZQwGAIT4-KAfZAQuAoRLIuZHEiVabPBAAN2UClQVCKgQpVIAQvZbqsrjcRATtrTKVQPkCeghILASqgwHAYQAKXyoQQKGhgKpPeqknz%20IrvACUhP5%20hodgQ4uVfgCTBN2Ca1yZIk1sX0toocAAFjQYFlydyxFAkAB3IJ0qiM1xUA0qpDq0529zIBQwAI2u22x3O11%20j3e33c4NGsOVfQg3PAsGgeGI5FcqkYyHYqC4s2EAlx3qKsyolBq76-d58-S%20KgQbGipCJBAAfTdqCQNLCkQIaXeeXDCHoSEQY6Q4utObOcCpakTLtHdKQC7zFBjK8PBsPG%2019qd%209XYlXx8qguoIrFQalMrlCpqF0NqootwlAOkg6CIgA-EUxDuNaCAgiCRYIki6YMpaPLvJiVY1qy6H1kSTYou2UBtmivILj2fZIAOQ7EvUB6UhOQRTlEs7zpUS7nox65avGCrblQu53lkDHjs%20-I1IkBqThErFznBJ7kK%20wqihKX6yvKdFmABTHvMBMCgeBMBQSQsEkPBBaglZykINi8AAIypj6LZQOKVwLCY6reEgDnJtyflid5vljlQAXGg0ACs7HgNA8C2T5cAAExOURaJueabJUNmIB2UlAWhauQV5SFYViGk0W5Yl%20VZJJ4ppJ6znEelQzyCMUDqnkXlWUAA)

Comment: thanks , unfortunately I cannot use this pattern, i want to keep if possible instances management, and a strong coupling for these instances which works on weakly coupled components.

Comment: @jon I made an update.

Comment: Ts seem not understand because this will break at `Token<T>`  , and `const test2 = new Token(KEYS.buffer);` will have any !

Comment: @jon sorry, I was not clear enough. I meant that you need to replace `Token` class in your example, not mine. Please see updated answer

Comment: yes is what i say `Property 'add' does not exist on type 'ValurBuffer<KEYS.buffer> | Valur<KEYS.buffer>'.
  Property 'add' does not exist on type 'Valur<KEYS.buffer>'.(2339)` look at end

Comment: `test2.valur.value`  and `test1.valur.value`  became any

Comment: @jon in order to handle it, you need create higher order function for `Token` class. But since you said it does not work for you, I don't know how to help you

Comment: oki thanks for your time , i will give you a "up" for your answer because it good and have nice idea :) and i will try more deep test to found something that's will allow me  this way! @+

Comment: i finally found a way that's allow me keep my pattern, i add a new playground.

Answer (score 0):

Found decent way
so because the conditional type is not considered evaluated.
assertion by wrapped the conditional type into another type seem ok and ts pass for constructor.

```
const enum KEYS {
    string = 'string',
    number = 'number',
    boolean = 'boolean',
    array = 'array',
    buffer = 'buffer',
}

type VALUES = {
    readonly [KEYS.string]: string;
    readonly [KEYS.number]: number;
    readonly [KEYS.boolean]: boolean;
    readonly [KEYS.array]: Array<string | number | boolean>;
    readonly [KEYS.buffer]: ReadonlyArray<Token<any>>;
}

type Helper<T extends KEYS> = T extends KEYS.buffer ? ValurBuffer<T> : Valur<T>;

export class Token<T extends KEYS> {
    // wrapped the conditional and ts say is ok now !
    readonly valur: Helper<T>;
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T) {
        // if KEYS.buffer ? is ValurBuffer or Valur ! why this no pass ?
        if (vtype === KEYS.buffer) {
            this.valur = new ValurBuffer(vtype) as Helper<T>;
        } else {
            this.valur = new Valur(vtype) as Helper<T>;
        }
    }
}


class Valur<T extends KEYS> {
    readonly Token: Token<T>;
    protected _value: VALUES[T];
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T, shemas?: {}) {}
}
class ValurBuffer<T extends KEYS.buffer> {
    readonly Token: Token<T>;
    protected readonly _value: VALUES[T];
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    add(v:VALUES[T]){}
    constructor(public readonly vtype: T, shemas?: {}) {}
}


const test1 = new Token(KEYS.array)
test1.valur.value;
test1.valur.value = [5];
const test2 = new Token(KEYS.buffer);
test2.valur.value
test2.valur.value=[];
test2.valur.add([new Token(KEYS.boolean)])
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgKZQK4FsEGkCiBNAZQQG9QFyF4AnASygHMEBeBAcmrvtYBoyK10AIyRVmbAcKo8+5QRAgAbJAEMoY1nMUqo0kBQTKqVZQE91h4yd37BqAGZ2R62w5G6AvqFBwTAByQIAGoAggAyAKo4RCykehRUKgAm0ApmANq4hAB0HAwAugBclHC0DADcMggJyslQqQgZ+ARZEiKFCK1UFXHk1bX1jdmaSqrtw9rd+n0p6ZnNFqbtwUamADy5jAA+HRiSCNvjqgB8k-FJMw1zWS6OVO0ASud1JsuWqwAqEADWKKuqJkcTqBPCBvH4AgAJJAKfxUD7IAAecBQiRg2CaRzE70RyKgqPRQ3stwQAH4gsoFKgqAAhIkiD6YoqBClUhndUBIBG+CBURBgBTKGBoz4-KDwzm4-FzTGxfQAejlCAA7sZfP5Egg4AALAKQPE0OA0aAUgx4zVomCmBA0NHfDoQJUIACElWmzwQADcWVQilCYfT3kCegg9dRUGA4DyABS+VCCBQ0MBVJ71D0+fxFd4AShIlXlipodgJzRuTjJNvJlJpdNEPMrVOdyq1Zm1FagEAQvkFaJJeYohYQUbT4OYTBYV1LVBzsv0s-IrZgWS9VbEUCQjuZVdprioQ-TSBzgoQfthbL75HcyAUMACM7n+gXS+9q-X9d3w-8h7RJ4DQfvCBBfQQRBLxwAFIU33FJEUTRaVc2DN16hFFBM2+X5A1OchfCoCBkQjJANQAfWXVAkCZMJIgINJ3jyTCEHoJBEBIpAo2nc9kzgKk1EfYiWSQOjAIoG8mL4oc+LY4MHy1G0sl4ykAhYZiBMqUMSnDSNd1jeNE2TGoLg-MiEHebhKB1dBBRJIpiHcadgNAfluzfbdbigyVYKaa4axlV0UzMZCoFQ0Uz2DbDcKQfCNUQsw5NI8iIiiajaMqBiRPk1j4P-BJOKobjpMXGL+MqQTyBqRIhwKEJ4qomis2slToDDCNoy0hMkyiz190zEyYDMiyrJskg7NBYbVM1JB4AARhfR1-KjK4FhMLNvHGuAJqfKt1tI7pkUmzaqE2hSGgAViS8AGsQHa4AAJmmoy0KgOaPMnLNtpWq69oO5b4Hekj9uYpg0lOy6fu9LJSqjNI1xm+7HqGeQRigLM8izIA)